# Equals method on Session Beans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, equals

I would like to show the results of the execution of the following code based on `EJB`:

```
@Stateless
public class StatelessBean implements IsStatelessBean{
...
}

@Stateful
public class StatefulBean implements IsStatefulBean{
...
}

@Singleton
public class SingletonBean implements IsSingletonBean{
...
}

@Stateless
public class MyBean {

@EJB
IsStatelessBean slBean1;
@EJB
IsStatelessBean slBean2;
@EJB
IsStatefulBean sfBean1;
@EJB
IsStatefulBean sfBean2;
@EJB
IsSingletonBean singlBean1;
@EJB
IsSingletonBean singlBean2;



    public String checkStatelessEqual() {
        String areEqual;
        if(slBean1.equals(slBean2))
            areEqual = "are equal!";
        else
            areEqual = "are NOT equal!";

        return "Stateless Beans "+areEqual;
    }


    public String checkStatefulEqual() {
        String areEqual;
        if(sfBean1.equals(sfBean2))
            areEqual = "are equal!";
        else
            areEqual = "are NOT equal!";

        return "Stateful Beans "+areEqual;
    }


    public String checkSingletonEqual() {
        String areEqual;
        if(singBean1.equals(singBean2))
            areEqual = "are equal!";
        else
            areEqual = "are NOT equal!";

        return "Singleton Beans "+areEqual;
    }

}
```

When I call the methods from the client the results are:

```
Stateless Beans are equal!
Stateful Beans are NOT equal!
Singleton Beans are equal!
```

I expected the `Singleton` Beans to be equal, but I did not expect the result for `Stateless` and `Stateful`.

1. Is it only a coincidence in this case that the `Container` gets the same instance of `Stateless` bean from the pool?
2. What is right about `Stateful`? Although they have only one client, is a new different reference created when a client injects it more than once?

Hint: The `equals` method is not overrided, consequently the only references are compared.

Comment: I think the output makes sense if you understand the implications of an object being either stateful or stateless. With stateless you don't care how many caller gets the reference to the same instance, after all it's stateless. But with stateful, as the name suggest an instance should not be shared among multiple callers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the expected behavior.

Regarding the stateless bean, from the ejb 3.1 spec (Sec. 3.4.7.1):

> All business object references of the same interface type for the same stateless session bean have the
>   same object identity...

and for the stateful bean, from the ejb 3.1 spec (Sec. 3.4.7.2):

> Stateful session bean references ... to different session bean instances will not have the same identity.

It makes sense, if you stick to the contract, you are guaranteed that invoking a business method on any of two instances of a stateless bean, will have the exact same effects, with a stateful bean that is not necessarily true.